# How do I read data from usb serial port?

Tags: javascript, serial-port, usb, port, webusb

I'm trying to read data from the USB serial port. It is a thermometer scanner. The connection was successful but I don't know how to read the result data. I'm getting the result like the image below. How do I decode the data?

[image]

Here is my code.

```
const reader = port.readable.getReader();

// Listen to data coming from the serial device.
while (true) {
  const { value, done } = await reader.read();
  if (done) {
    // Allow the serial port to be closed later.
    reader.releaseLock();
    break;
  }
  // value is a Uint8Array.
  console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: Can you add details about the model of your device? Does the manufacturer provide documentation on the data that it sends over the serial connection?

Comment: @ReillyGrant Hello, the model of the device is K3 Pro Thermometer scanner. It is human temperature scanner. The manufacturer does not provide any documentation on the data, but the manufacturer have a software that can be installed on windows and will display the temperature after it is scanned from the temperature device.

Comment: It sounds like you're unfortunately going to have to do some reverse engineering of the data format then.

Comment: @ReillyGrant maybe reverse engineering is the way, I will try it then.